# UIScrollView doesn't show scrollers (scroll indicators)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I have UIScrollView which i populate with UIImageViews programmatically. After that I change contentSize of scrollview so I can scroll it. It works fine, but I don't see scrollers and it bothers me. I've set to show them in .xib, and I've even set "showHorizontalScrollIndicator" property programmatically, but I still can't see scrollers.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't see scrollbars and how I can make them appear?

BTW I don't mean I wan't to see them at all times, I just want standard behavior, but they aren't shown even when I'm scrolling.

Comment: are you sure the size of the scroller is not out of super view bounds?

Comment: Size of scrollview, you say? Yes, it's not out of bounds. If you mean something else - please clarify.

Comment: You might be removing all the subviews of your scrollview, including scroll indicators.

Comment: As a matter of fact yes, yes I was removing all subviews. Now I'm checking class before removing subview. Thank you. Post it as an answer, because it's the right one. At least for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was removing subviews and scroll indicators were of them.

I fixed it at first by checking type of subviews I was removing,
then I changed the logic and didn't remove subviews at all.

Comment: Just discovered I was doing that too. Well spotted Protheus & erkanyildiz!